# jQuery ajax call fires error event on a 200 success call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP.NET Core WebAPI project with the following GET in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

I'm trying to call this method from jQuery ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        setJsonResult(data);
        showResultPane("API request result");
    },
    error: function (obj, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        setHtmlResult("Error returned by API: " + errorThrown);
        showResultPane("Unauthorized request result");
    },
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        if (currentToken) {
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + currentToken);
        }
    }
});
```

I monitor the web traffic with Fiddler and I see that the server returns a 200 Ok response with the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,     Accept, Authorization
Date: Thu, 08 Jun 2017 09:13:18 GMT

13
["value1","value2"]
0
```

The problem is that while the response from the web server is successful, the jQuery ajax error method is still being fired instead of the success method. I've tried playing with the `dataType` parameter (changing it, removing it) - no effect.

I even tried returning a different value from the API that is just a string and even change `dataType` to `text` - still firing error.

What's going on here?

Comment: This happens when the response cannot be parsed to the dataType you specified, in your case JSON. This is because you've prefixed the returned JSON string with `13` and `0` respectively. Remove those values, wherever they are coming from

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I did not prefix it (As you can see from the code above). Even if I do the request from Postman it still returns those numbers - and Postman is able to parse it.

Comment: That's very odd then. Do you have a custom serialiser in use? The problem is definitely those numbers in the response preventing deserialisation

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no custom serializer  - just a brand new webapi project

Comment: Ok, well I'm afraid I cannot offer a solution to the problem with the information you've given. The issue is 100% caused by the additional data in the body of the response. You'll need to debug the ASP code to determine where that is coming from

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have chacked other APIs on the net - they all return those pre and post numbers. Probably part of http protocol.

Comment: I've written a lot of APIs - admittedly none yet in .Net Core - and none of them have the wrapped data. It is not part of the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Just to be sure - I've created a completely new API project in .NET and ran it in the browser - exactly the same result - I give some credit to Microsoft that they know what they are doing when giving you that initial template - it should at least work for a simple test case.

Comment: I just tried it myself in a project I'm working on right now, this was the result I got: https://jsfiddle.net/vfno3gho/ - excuse the fiddle, it was just the easiest way to send the text clearly :)

Comment: What kind of WebAPI project? .NET Core?

Comment: I just noticed that when executing the request the ajax call is first generating a call with a 204 result (for cross origin calls) - is this related?

Comment: Possibly, although a 204 is not related to cross domain content. 204 means 'No Content'

Comment: I found the solution. See my answer to this question below. It had to do with ASP.NET CORS policy. the "wrapping numbers" are still there and are not interrupting. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution - don't yet understand the full extent of it. Basically it had to do with ASP.NET CORS policy. So for now I just enabled everything:

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have specified return datatype to be json and the API is not returning a valid json. Try changing the return type of your method to JsonResult and return valid jsonstring from your method. You can also check the response json is valid in this site :https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: You can see from the result that the returned type is `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: And if I take `["value1","value2"]` to the website you suggested it returns that it is a valid json

Comment: Try changing 'IEnumerable<string>' to JsonResult and check if there is any change in the response in fiddler. Or Try like this                     
    public string Get()
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
           return jsSerializer.Serialize(new string[] { "value1", "value2" });         
        }

Comment: Tried it. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

The response does not look like valid JSON to me. Change the return for the Get()-method to string and try to serialize the response from with JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize() before returning it.

Also try setting dataType to 'application/json' and add *crossDomain: true* in the ajax-call.

I have only experience with self-hosted wcf application, but there I'm using [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json] attributes for my REST-methods.